# Path Based Listener Rule on Application Load Balancer doesn't forward to the Target Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

I have below path based listener setting. Each Target Group set up on IP address target type on different ports.
Client on port 3000
Safety on port 5070
Action on port 5010

On default action, it successfully forward to the Target Group. But when I set it up as a path based, it fails to forward to the selected Target Group.

[Listener rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5Dvd.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your target groups (TGs) must respond to `/api/safety` and `/client`. ALB does not do any re-writing of paths. So any incoming path, must be a valid path in your application.